# How does one perform math on multiple SELECT results?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an sql table of PlayerTrial that holds, well, player trials.

```
---PlayerTrials Basic Layout---
int id
int playerid
bool flagA
bool flagB
bool flagC
```

I want to determine the % of trials a player has done with flags B and C set.

To do so, I know I have to:

1) Select the total trials by a single player

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) from playertrial WHERE playerid = _
```

2) Select the total trials with flagB and flagC true

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) from playertrial WHERE playerid = _ AND flagB = true AND flagC = true
```

3) divide 2 by 1 to determine the % of trials with flags B+C set

```
brain explode.
```

I know how to do the individual queries for both one and two. And of course I could store them in a temporary table or something. But I'm sure there's a way to join them into one query, and I have fried my brain trying all the SQL combos I know such that I don't have a clue what to try next. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT BCCount, TotalCount, BCCount/TotalCount as Percentage
    FROM (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN flagB=true AND flagC=true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BCCount,
                 COUNT(*) as TotalCount
              FROM playertrial
              WHERE playerid = _) t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm. Seems like it was second nature to you...kudos.