# perform math on multiple SELECT results in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Similar to this question [How does one perform math on multiple SELECT results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504489/how-does-one-perform-math-on-multiple-select-results)

Cant make mine work.

I want to determine the % of Shipments that are were sent on time.

To do so, I know I have to:

1) Select the total shipments sent.

```
Select COUNT(*) AS TotalShipments From tbl_LISC
```

2) Select the total shipments sent **OnTime**

```
Select COUNT(*) AS TotalOnTime From tbl_LISC WHERE tbl_LISC.LISC = 100
```

3) Divide the 2 results and multiply by 100 ( (**TotalOnTime/TotalShipments)*100** )

Following the answer of the thread as an example I tried

```
SELECT TotalShipped, TotalOnTime, TotalShipped/TotalOnTime as LISC
FROM (SELECT COUNT(Select *From tbl_LISC) AS TotalShipped,
             COUNT(*) as TotalOnTime
          FROM tbl_LISC
          WHERE LISC = 0)
```

Comment: so according to first query, all records in `tbl_LISC` table are "not on time" and out of those "not on time", `LISC =100` are on time?

Comment: Sorry wrong name on that one, Edit, they are the total of shipments if its not 100 than it counts as a late

Comment: Please add a tag for the specific RDBMS you're using: mysql, sql-server, oracle, etc.

Comment: I'm using sql-server for the moment @Barmar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your real problem is integer versus floating point math. When both numbers of the expression are integers, the result will also be an integer:

```
select 2/3 -- 0
```

So, in order to preserve decimal precision, simply make one of the numbers in the expression a decimal/float value:

```
select 2.0/3 -- 0.666666
```

So, try this on for size:

```
select
 sum(iif(tbl_LISC.LISC = 100, 1, 0)) as OnTime
,count(*) as Total
,sum(iif(tbl_LISC.LISC = 100, 1.0, 0.0)) / nullif(count(*), 0) as Percentage
from tbl_LISC as l
```